# Batch render multiple scenes code give's me error

Tags: rendering

I am trying this script

`blender -b file.blend -S Scene1 -a -S Scene2 -a` in Blender's Script tab, but it says  `Invalid syntax on line 1`.

What I am doing wrong. I am using Blender 3.3 on a Win 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That's a *shell* command.

Blender's script tab is for writing Python scripts. The command for batch rendering should be run in a terminal or shell of some kind (The Terminal app on Mac, I'm not sure what on Windows.)